# How to open a login,registration and forget password form in a popup programmatically?

Tags: 7, forms

I want to open a user login form in popup after click on user link same as under login form I have create new account link I also want this to popup.. I have used 2-3 modules like modal_form colorbox etc. Its not full-filling my need. Because I need to customize my login form.

Comment: I have included in my question modal window is not successful in my case.

Comment: No you've mentioned that a specific module called modal_form didn't fit your needs, but even then you haven't given any indication as to what you tried to do with it, or why that didn't work. Either way, read through the duplicate: there are several alternatives provided. If you end up trying all of those, and none of them do what you want, then ask a new question but make sure you detail _specifically_ how you tried to configure each of the modules, and _specifically_ why they failed to meet your requirements

Comment: Didn't you mean _programmatically_? The title says _grammatically_, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: by mistake.. I mean programmatically

Comment: I have used modal_form but its not fit.. Because i need to customize my login and registration form. and changes are not showing on this popup.. for better layout I am using betterlogin drupal module.

Comment: model_form also not showing fbconnect button on login form.

Comment: So use one of the other ones @jsh

Comment: I have also used popup_form module and colorbox. but not finding any solution.. colorbox not fetching all points of login form only showing username and password